# Best way to put commas into large numbers

Tags: sql-server, number-formatting

I've started a new job and it involves looking at a bunch of big numbers. Is there an easy way to add commas to an `int` or `decimal` field to make it readable?

For example, SQL Server outputs the column on the left, but for my own sanity, I need it to look like the one on the right:

```
2036150 -> 2,036,150
```

...or would I have to write some heinous

```
left(right(vandalized_data),6),3) + ',' + right(left(vandalized_data),6),3)
```

function?

The perfect thing would be commas in the display grid, then plain integers in the output.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you're on SQL Server 2012+, and you want to do it (without decimal places):

```
SELECT x = FORMAT(2036150, N'N0')
```

If you're on an earlier version, you have to jump through some hoops:

```
SELECT x = REPLACE(CONVERT(nvarchar(30), CONVERT(money, 2036150), 1), N'.00', N'');
```

Answer (score 19):

TSQL's [FORMAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function can do that.  EG

```
select format(1232131312342132123.2222,'0,###.##')
```

outputs

```
1,232,131,312,342,132,123.22
```

If you want to use a different separator, you still use `,` which has a [special meaning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings) in .Net format string, and then replace the `,` with something else.  EG:

```
select replace(format(123445678.2222,'#,###.##'),',','_')
```

outputs

```
123_445_678.22
```